# Kafka Sink Connector with custom consumer-group name

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

In kafka connect, all the sink connectors will use the different group with the naming conversion of `connect-connector_name`. But I want to use a custom name as the prefix.(we can do in the sink config - `name properties`, but looking for set it by default)

I tried to setup this in the `consumer.properties` file, but no use.

Does anyone know how it set it? also, What happens if I set a single group for all my sink connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sink tasks default to have `connect-` prefix for their `ConsumerConfig` `group.id`

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4400

Update: You can override with `consumer.override.group.id` and policy override on the worker (note: this is not enabled in environments like MSK, last I checked)

---

`consumer.properties` is used (optionally) for `kafka-console-consumer`, not Connect API

---

> happens if I set a single group for all my sink connector?

You mean a single connector with one `name`? Then you'd want `tasks.max` to be equal to the total partitions of all topics its consuming.

If you mean multiple connectors, then you can't; all connectors within the same Connect cluster need a unique `name`/`connector.class` pair

Answer (score 3):

You can override any consumer or producer properties. You have to use  `connector.client.config.override.policy = All` in worker configuration (default is `None`). Then you can override consumer.group.id for your task in property `consumer.override.group.id`. For example:

```
{
  "consumer.override.group.id": "testgroup",
  "name": "Elasticsearch",
  "config": {
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "topics": "orders",
  "tasks.max": 1,
  "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
  "type.name": "type.name=kafkaconnect",
  "key.ignore": "true",
  "schema.ignore": "false",
  "transforms": "renameTopic",
  "transforms.renameTopic.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
  "transforms.renameTopic.regex": "orders",
  "transforms.renameTopic.replacement": "orders-latest"
}'
```

Documentation [is here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration)

If you use kafka-connect in docker from image `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connnect-base`, you can set this configuration from environment variable `CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY`